# How to popup instead of echo

Tags: php, html, popup, echo

I have created a contact form using HTML and PHP.

Right now when a user submit the contact form he redirect to a new page with the echo message, instead, I want this message to appears in a small popup window.

HTML Code:

```html
        <form action="/assets/bootstrap/php/emailscript.php" method="post">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="Name" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter your name')"
    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" required >
          <input type="text" placeholder="Company" name="Company" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter your Company name')"
    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" required >
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="Email" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid e-mail address')"
    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" >
          <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="Subject" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a Subject')"
    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" required >
          <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Message" name="Message" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please Write your Message')"
    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" required ></textarea>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send</button>
           
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PHP Code:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Name']))
{
    $name=$_POST['Name'] ;
    $company=$_POST['Company'] ;
    $from=$_POST['Email'] ;
    $message=$_POST['Message'] ;
    $to="contact@website.com" ;
    $subject="Website contact form";

$headers .= 'From: '.$name.' |  '.$company.' |  '.$from.' ' . "\r\n";

    mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ;

    echo "Your Email has bean sent.";


}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: You need AJAX for this. Google has more details on how to replace a form submit with an ajax call

Comment: can i do it with the HTML code instead of PHP and AJAX?

Comment: No, you need PHP and AJAX. HTML is just a markup language.